# Android - Overriding onTextChanged doesn't change behavior

Tags: android, text, view

I'm attempting to create a custom EditText that will implement a delay before executing onTextChanged.

```
class CustomEditText(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : AppCompatEditText(context, attributeSet) {

     private var millisDelay: Long = 500

     private var timer: Timer? = null

     override fun onTextChanged(
         text: CharSequence?,
         start: Int,
         lengthBefore: Int,
         lengthAfter: Int
     ) {
         doDelay {
             Log.d("somekoder", "Calling onTextChanged after $millisDelay milliseconds")
             super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter)
         }
     }

     fun setDelay(millisDelay: Long){
         this.millisDelay = millisDelay
     }

     private fun doDelay(then: () -> Unit){
         timer?.cancel()
         timer = Timer()
         // Log.d("somekoder", "Got action. Waiting $millisDelay milliseconds.")
         timer?.schedule(timerTask {
             then.invoke()
         }, millisDelay)
     }
}
```

Here's in my MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        search.setDelay(1000)

        search.addTextChangedListener {
            Log.d("somekoder", "MainActivity: onTextChanged")
        }
    }
}
```

This is what my logs look like:

```
D/somekoder: MainActivity: onTextChanged
D/somekoder: MainActivity: onTextChanged
D/somekoder: MainActivity: onTextChanged
D/somekoder: MainActivity: onTextChanged
D/somekoder: Calling onTextChanged after 1000 milliseconds
```

MainActivity onTextChanged gets invoked even though I have a delay in there.
Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`onTextChanged` method is a protected one which works like an inner listener for `TextView` subclasses. The default implementation is empty and it gets called when text is changed and after listeners. So it is completely independent of listeners.

If you want to delay listeners (not the text changing) you can do something like this. But I don't recommend it because I think it can cause problems especially in `afterTextChanged` (as it can change the text).

```kotlin
    override fun addTextChangedListener(watcher: TextWatcher) {
        super.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                doDelay {
                    watcher.beforeTextChanged(s, start, count, after)
                }
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                doDelay {
                    watcher.onTextChanged(s, start, before, count)
                }
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                doDelay {
                    watcher.afterTextChanged(s)
                }
            }

        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

with addTextChangedListener() you can add multiple listener not like setOnclickListener where you can set only One listener at a time. As a general api implementation you have two listeners to your view. In your case both implemenation are different. Delay won't affect other listener execution.